# Changing responses left blank with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, string

I have a script that is asking for an alternative address but not requiring the fields.  The email response is saying "undefined" on all fields that are left blank.

Is there a way to customize the response that App Scripts gives to fields left blank, either actually leave them empty in the response email or the words "no answer" as opposed to "undefined"?

I'm creating a bunch of variables from a Google Form submission.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var toAddress = e.values[1];
 var myFirstName = e.values[2];
 var myLastName = e.values[3];
 var myCertifications = e.values[4];
 var myEmployer = e.values[5];
 var myPhoneNumber = e.values[6];
 var myAltPhoneNumber = e.values[7];
 var myFax = e.values[8];
 var myBirthday = e.values[9];
 var myWorkAddy = e.values[10];
 var myWorkAddy2 = e.values[11];
 var myWorkCity = e.values[12];
 var myWorkState = e.values[13];
 var myWorkZip = e.values[14];
 var myAltAddy = e.values[15];
 var myAltAddy2 = e.values[16];
 var myAltCity = e.values[17];
 var myAltState = e.values[18];
 var myAltZip = e.values[19];
 var mySnailPref = e.values[20];
 var myQuestions = e.values[21];
```

I then email the variable data.  Everything works fine IF all fields are filled out by the user, but some of the fields are not required.  When they leave a field blank, the script doesn't put the data in the proper place in the email.

What can I add below these variables so that IF someone doesn't answer one of the questions, it says, "Not Answered"?

Newest Edit Starts Here:

I tried Serge's approach, numerous different ways and I can't seem to get it correct.

It kind of works, but it seems to set variables that are required form fields to "undefined".

Here is a link to a copy of the sheet.  Feel free to look and edit the script.  If someone can get it right all come back here and leave the answer for others to learn.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RkAdssA9dwef_ZeknAlE1rZKEYlO0xs-cJZQir0-9jg/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script in it's entirety definitions.

```
 function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var toAddress = e.values[1];
  var myFirstName = e.values[2];
  var myLastName = e.values[3];
  var myCertifications = e.values[4]!=null? e.values[4] : 'no answer';
  var myEmployer = e.values[5]!=null? e.values[5] : 'no answer';
  var myPhoneNumber = e.values[6];
  var myAltPhoneNumber = e.values[7]!=null? e.values[7] : 'no answer';
  var myFax = e.values[8]!=null? e.values[8] : 'no answer';
  var myBirthday = e.values[9]!=null? e.values[9] : 'no answer';
  var myWorkAddy = e.values[10];
  var myWorkAddy2 = e.values[11]!=null? e.values[11] : 'no answer';
  var myWorkCity = e.values[12];
  var myWorkState = e.values[13];
  var myWorkZip = e.values[14];
  var myAltAddy = e.values[15]!=null? e.values[15] : 'no answer';
  var myAltAddy2 = e.values[16]!=null? e.values[16] : 'no answer';
  var myAltCity = e.values[17]!=null? e.values[17] : 'no answer';
  var myAltState = e.values[18]!=null? e.values[18] : 'no answer';
  var myAltZip = e.values[19]!=null? e.values[19] : 'no answer';
  var mySnailPref = e.values[20];
  var myQuestions = e.values[21]!=null? e.values[21] : 'no answer';

  var emailreplyTo = "dave@davelalande.com" ;
  var subject = "Membership Application";
  var emailBody = myFirstName + ", " +
   "\n\nThank you for your Association Registration." +
   "\nThe information we received is as follows." +
   "\n\nFirst Name: " + myFirstName +
   "\nLast Name: " + myLastName +
   "\nCurrent Certifications: " + myCertifications +
   "\nEmployer: " + myEmployer +
   "\nPhone Number: " + myPhoneNumber +
   "\nAlternative Phone Number: " + myAltPhoneNumber +
   "\nFax: " + myFax +
   "\nBirthday and Birth Month: " + myBirthday +
   "\nWork Address: " + myWorkAddy +
   "\nWork Address 2: " + myWorkAddy2 +
   "\nWork City: " + myWorkCity +
   "\nWork State: " + myWorkState +
   "\nWork ZIP: " + myWorkZip +
   "\nAlternaitive Address: " + myAltAddy +
   "\nAlternative Address 2: " + myAltAddy2 +
   "\nAlternative Address City: " + myAltCity +
   "\nAlternative Address State: " + myAltState +
   "\nAlternative Address ZIP: " + myAltZip +
   "\nSnail Mail Address Preference: " + mySnailPref +
   "\nYour Question or Comment: " + myQuestions +
   "\n\nPlease print this page and mail it with a check in the amount of $25.00, payable to the Association." +
   "\n\nMail it to:" +
   "\nDave Lalande" +
   "\n123 Main" +
   "\nSuite 240" +
   "\nAny Town, MO  65201" +
   "\n\nYour membership will become active when the dues have been received and processed. " +
   "\nYou will receive an email notifying you when your membership has been activated. Welcome to the Association! " +
   "\n\nIf you have questions please email me at dave@davelalande.com. ";


var htmlBody = myFirstName +"," +
   "<br/><br/>Thank you for your Missouri State Tumor Registrars' Association (MoSTRA) Registration. " +
   "<br/>The information we received is as follows." +
   "<br/><br/>First Name: " + myFirstName +
   "<br/>Last Name: " + myLastName +
   "<br/>Current Certifications: " + myCertifications +
   "<br/>Employer: " + myEmployer +
   "<br/>Phone Number: " + myPhoneNumber +
   "<br/>Alternative Phone Number: " + myAltPhoneNumber +
   "<br/>Fax: " + myFax +
   "<br/>Birthday and Birth Month: " + myBirthday +
   "<br/>Work Address: " + myWorkAddy +
   "<br/>Work Address 2: " + myWorkAddy2 +
   "<br/>Work City: " + myWorkCity +
   "<br/>Work City: " + myWorkState +
   "<br/>Work City: " + myWorkZip +
   "<br/>Alternative Address: " + myAltAddy +
   "<br/>Alternative Address 2: " + myAltAddy2 +
   "<br/>Alternative Address City: " + myAltCity +
   "<br/>Alternative Address State: " + myAltState +
   "<br/>Alternative Address ZIP: " + myAltZip +
   "<br/>Snail Mail Address Preference: " + mySnailPref +
   "<br/>Your Question or Comment: " + myQuestions +
   "<br/><br/>Please print this page and mail it with a check in the amount of $25.00, payable to the Association. " +
   "<br/><br/>Mail it to: " +
   "<br/><br/>Dave Lalande " +
   "<br/>123 Main " +
   "<br/>Suite 240 " +
   "<br/>Any Town, MO  65201 " +
   "<br/><br/>Your membership will become active when the dues have been received and processed. " +
   "<br/>You will receive an email notifying you when your membership has been activated. Welcome to the Association! " +
   "<br/><br/>If you have questions please email me at dave@davelalande.com. ";


var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo:emailreplyTo, name: "Membership Chair", htmlBody: htmlBody};

MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject, emailBody, optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

Comment: Can you include some example code? Is this a script as a published web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a short form condition on every item like in the example below :

```
function myFunction() {
  var e = {};
  e.values='';// these 2 lines only to create test conditions...
//  var test = e.values[0]; // uncomment this line to test "normal" behavior without condition
  var test = e.values[0]!=null? e.values[0] : 'no answer';// example with condition
  Logger.log(test);// see result in logger
}
```

See documentation on this conditional operation here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

---

edit -suggestion to try- : the idea is to replace empty strings in the `e object` with a predefined string  (doing that after having converted the object to a string) and parsing it back to an object.
(I didn't test it)
code should go like this :

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var e_string = JSON.stringify(e);
  e=JSON.parse(e_string.replace(/""/g,'not answered'));
  var toAddress = e.values[1];
  var myFirstName = e.values[2];
  var myLastName = e.values[3];
  //.... continue your function unchanged
}
```

(edit note : this does not work in this context... it would be useable in a UiApp form using a doGet/doPost structure but not with Google Forms,... sorry for the waste of time)

---

### EDIT 2

Got it to work but I had to modify your initial approach...
instead of getting the values by their index (`values[n]`) I use the items names...

The code goes like this :

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var items = FormApp.openById('1r67Ny2hWl5Su2wtzKKoT5a4ITE1FkKfJigZx0hMXvkU').getItems();
  for(var n = 0 ; n < items.length; n++){
    Logger.log(n+'  - '+items[n].getTitle()+' == ? '+e.namedValues[items[n].getTitle()]);
    if(e.namedValues[items[n].getTitle()]==null){e.namedValues[items[n].getTitle()] = 'no answer'}
  }
  var toAddress = e.namedValues[items[0].getTitle()];
  var myFirstName = e.namedValues[items[1].getTitle()];
  var myLastName = e.namedValues[items[2].getTitle()];
  var myCertifications = e.namedValues[items[3].getTitle()];
  var myEmployer = e.namedValues[items[4].getTitle()];
  var myPhoneNumber = e.namedValues[items[5].getTitle()];
  var myAltPhoneNumber = e.namedValues[items[6].getTitle()];
  var myFax = e.namedValues[items[7].getTitle()];
  var myBirthday = e.namedValues[items[8].getTitle()];
  var myWorkAddy = e.namedValues[items[11].getTitle()];
  var myWorkAddy2 = e.namedValues[items[12].getTitle()];
  var myWorkCity = e.namedValues[items[13].getTitle()];
  var myWorkState = e.namedValues[items[14].getTitle()];
  var myWorkZip = e.namedValues[items[15].getTitle()];
  var myAltAddy = e.namedValues[items[17].getTitle()];
  var myAltAddy2 = e.namedValues[items[18].getTitle()];
  var myAltCity = e.namedValues[items[19].getTitle()];
  var myAltState = e.namedValues[items[20].getTitle()];
  var myAltZip = e.namedValues[items[21].getTitle()];
  var mySnailPref = e.namedValues[items[23].getTitle()];
  var myQuestions = e.namedValues[items[24].getTitle()];

  var emailreplyTo = "dave@davelalande.com" ;
  var subject = "Membership Application";
  var htmlBody = myFirstName +"," +
       "<br><br>Thank you for your Missouri State Tumor Registrars' Association (MoSTRA) Registration. " +
       "<br>The information we received is as follows." +
       "<br><br>First Name: " + myFirstName +
       "<br>Last Name: " + myLastName +
       "<br>Current Certifications: " + myCertifications +
       "<br>Employer: " + myEmployer +
       "<br>Phone Number: " + myPhoneNumber +
       "<br>Alternative Phone Number: " + myAltPhoneNumber +
       "<br>Fax: " + myFax +
       "<br>Birthday and Birth Month: " + myBirthday +
       "<br>Work Address: " + myWorkAddy +
       "<br>Work Address 2: " + myWorkAddy2 +
       "<br>Work City: " + myWorkCity +
       "<br>Work City: " + myWorkState +
       "<br>Work City: " + myWorkZip +
       "<br>Alternative Address: " + myAltAddy +
       "<br>Alternative Address 2: " + myAltAddy2 +
       "<br>Alternative Address City: " + myAltCity +
       "<br>Alternative Address State: " + myAltState +
       "<br>Alternative Address ZIP: " + myAltZip +
       "<br>Snail Mail Address Preference: " + mySnailPref +
       "<br>Your Question or Comment: " + myQuestions +
       "<br><br>Please print this page and mail it with a check in the amount of $25.00, payable to the Association. " +
       "<br><br>Mail it to: " +
       "<br><br>Dave Lalande " +
       "<br>123 Main " +
       "<br>Suite 240 " +
       "<br>Any Town, MO  65201 " +
       "<br><br>Your membership will become active when the dues have been received and processed. " +
       "<br>You will receive an email notifying you when your membership has been activated. Welcome to the Association! " +
       "<br><br>If you have questions please email me at dave@davelalande.com. ";
  var emailBody = htmlBody.replace(/<br>/g,'\n');
  var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo:emailreplyTo, name: "Membership Chair", htmlBody: htmlBody};
  Logger.log(emailBody);
  MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject, emailBody, optAdvancedArgs);
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hnnpK5MAUET8QHIezFP9LskHf9Q-SMNwDpNkIpcWGbM').getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var r in data){
    for(var c in data[0]){
      if(data[r][c]==''){data[r][c]='no answer'}
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hnnpK5MAUET8QHIezFP9LskHf9Q-SMNwDpNkIpcWGbM').getSheets()[0].getDataRange().setValues(data);
}
```

NOTE : you will have to edit your form to avoid duplicate names in the item descriptions... right now there are 2 fields called "address" , "zip" etc... so it fails to detect them properly but that wouldn't be to hard to work out !

Note also that if you do so you'll have to unlink the form from the spreadsheet and relink it afterwards so that the columns in the sheet correspond to the new item titles and the form responses match their definitions in the script as well (you can of course reuse the same spreadsheet but use a new sheet in it).

I added in the comments a link to an updated form that works flawlessly.

Actually I also changed the mail construction part, getting the text version directly from the html version (since you only used `br` tags, I simply replaced these tags by a `\n` to get the plain text version) to make the code a bit shorter..

I also added an automatic update of the spreadsheet (I saw in another post that you wanted to mark the empty cells in the sheet as well), filling the empty cells with 'no answer'.

Well, I guess I'm done with modifications now ! enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks Serge.  The conditional code I have in my question does work for one of the variable.  I was wondering if there was some blank code that said, "If any of the above variables are undefined or null then do this"?  I gather from your answer I have to put my code after each variable and there is no way to provide a blanket condition.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just tested again and actually my code doesn't work, it changes it to "no answer".

Comment: Thinking about your problem, I've had an idea but I'm definitely not sure it will work... please give it a try and tell me what happens ;) (added in answer)

Comment: Nope. :) Many are undefined and the email is mixed up answers next to the labels.

Comment: Serge, I wouldn't know how to write it and it seems like a work around but what if there was a script that ran before this mail answers script that set any null/undefined to "Not Answered"?  Then the mail answer could run and nothing would be undefined.

Comment: Please see edit 2 .I also sent you a test mail showing the result.

Comment: link to working example, I shared it with you and is viewable by anybody.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hnnpK5MAUET8QHIezFP9LskHf9Q-SMNwDpNkIpcWGbM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found a shorter solution:

```
// get the last response
var allResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
var lastResponses = allResponses[allResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

// convert values into dictionary
var response = {};
for (var i = 0; i < lastResponses.length; i++) {
  response[lastResponses[i].getItem().getTitle()] = lastResponses[i].getResponse();
}

// access values like this (directly in code)
var full name = response['first name'] + response['last name']
```